# RESOLVED - Symfony5 - The controller for URI "/sitemap.xml" is not callable

Tags: php, xml, symfony

I'm working on a SitemapController, but when I'm going on my /sitemap.xml and my custom ErrorController is empty, it throws me an error :

```
"SyntaxError > InvalidArgumentException > InvalidArgumentException > InvalidArgumentException > InvalidArgumentException - HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
The controller for URI "/sitemap.xml" is not callable: Expected method "show" on class "App\Controller\ErrorController". Available methods: "setContainer", "getSubscribedServices".
```

And when my ErrorController is not empty (and returns a 404), I get this :

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 4 at column 17: Specification mandates value for attribute async
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Here's my controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\PostRepository;
use App\Service\Image\ImagePathGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class SitemapController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
      * @Route("/sitemap.xml", name="sitemap", defaults={"_format"="xml"})
     */
    public function index(Request $request, ImagePathGenerator $imagePathGenerator, PostRepository $postRepository): Response
    {
        // Récupérer le nom d'hôte
        $hostname = $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
        
        // On initialise un tableau pour lister les URL
        $urls = [];
        
        // On ajoute les URLs statiques
        $urls[] = ['loc' => $this->generateUrl('home')];
        $urls[] = ['loc' => $this->generateUrl('blog_index')];
        $urls[] = ['loc' => $this->generateUrl('app_login')];
        
        // On ajoute les URLs dynamiques
        foreach($postRepository->findAll() as $post){
            if($post->getImage()->getName() !== null){
                $images = [
                    'loc' => $imagePathGenerator->generate($post->getImage()->getName(), 300, 200),
                    'title' => $post->getTitle()
                ];
            } else {
                $images = '';
            }
            
            
            $urls[] = [
                'loc' => $this->generateUrl('blog_show', ['id' => $post->getId(), 'slug' => $post->getSlug()]),
                'image' => $images,
                'lastmod' => $post->getCreatedAt()->format('Y-m-d')
            ];
        }

        // Fabriquer la réponse
        $response = new Response(
            $this->renderView('sitemap/index.html.twig', [
                'urls' => $urls,
                'hostname' => $hostname
                ]),
                200
            );
            
            
            // Ajout des entêtes
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
            
            // Envoyer la réponse
            return $response;
        }
        
    }
```

And my twig file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

    {% for url in urls %}
        <url>
            <loc>
                {% if url.loc|replace(hostname:'') == url.loc %}
                    {{hostname}}{{url.loc}}
                {% else %}
                    {{url.loc}}
                {% endif %}
            </loc>
            {% if url.lastmod is defined %}
                <lastmod>{{url.lastmod}}</lastmod>
            {% endif %}

            {% if url.changefreq is defined %}
                <changefreq>{{url.changefreq}}</changefreq>
            {% endif %}

            {% if url.priority is defined %}
                <priority>{{url.priority}}</priority>
            {% endif %}
            {% if url.image is defined and url.image is not empty %}
                <image:image>
                    <image:loc>
                        {% if url.image.loc|replace({hostname:''}) == url.image.loc %}
                            {{hostname}}{{url.image.loc}}
                        {% else %}
                            {{url.image.loc}}
                        {% endif %} 
                    </image:loc>
                    <image:title>{{ url.image.title }}</image:title>
                </image:image>
            {% endif %}
        </url>
    {% endfor %}

</urlset>
```

EDIT: Actually, the route seems working when there is no loop in the twig file. I can add xml tags and it works fine. The error appears when I'm starting the first loop. Even $hostname variable works in the twig file.

If someone can help me, I would highly appreciate... :)

Comment: Hello! Could you show us your config/routing.yaml?

Comment: Yep, of course !

`framework:
    router:
        utf8: true`

Comment: I found what happened. In the twig file, line 7, I forgot to put "hostname" between { }. It works fine now.

Comment: cool, have a good day